# Reshape a Shiny table

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to create a (pseudo-) Confusion Matrix with `shiny` wherein the cutoff of the continuous predicted value used for classification can be set by the user.

The table works fine except that `shiny` or `xtable` is reshaping the table.

The `tableOutput` appears like this:

```
Var1     Var2    Freq
FALSE    FALSE   0.89
TRUE     FALSE   0.11
FALSE    TRUE    0.00
TRUE     TRUE    1.00
```

Whereas the way it looks in R (without using `shiny`) is:

```
            FALSE      TRUE
  FALSE 0.8888889 0.1111111
  TRUE  0.0000000 1.0000000
```

which is what I want.

**ui.R**

```
pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel('Pseudo Confusion Matrix'),
  sidebarPanel(
    numericInput('cutoff', 'ML Score Cutoff', .005,
                 min = .001, max = .5, step = .01)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput('tab1')
  )
)
```

**server.R**

```
conf_mat <- data.frame(Y = train$Y,
                       Score = vscoreHex$p1_nml)

function(input, output, session) {

  cutoffs <- reactive({
    prop.table(table(conf_mat$Y > 0, conf_mat$Score >= input$cutoff),1) 
  })

  output$tab1 <- renderTable({
    cutoffs()
  })

}
```

**Example Data**

```
conf_mat <-
structure(list(Y = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Score = c(0.0107176032176252, 
0.00151343289438336, 0.00151343289438336, 0.00118417125401831, 
0.00151343289438336, 0.00151343289438336, 0.00151343289438336, 
0.00151343289438336, 0.000769538494171191, 0.0107176032176252
)), .Names = c("Y", "Score"), row.names = c(4477L, 14923L, 12792L, 
49773L, 27827L, 55772L, 36056L, 51987L, 71856L, 27531L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I've found a solution but please add your answer in case your solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can convert to data.frame with `as.data.frame.matrix` and then use the `rownames = TRUE` in `renderTable`

```
-
-
cutoffs <- reactive({
   as.data.frame.matrix(prop.table(table(conf_mat$Y > 0, conf_mat$Score >= input$cutoff),1))
 })

 output$tab1 <- renderTable({
  cutoffs()
  }, rownames = TRUE)

 }
-
-
```

-output

[image]